# How to pass class from .dll to webservice, without copying it's fields

Tags: c#, web-services, dll

I have class (f.e Automobile) on WebService and in Dll (what use this web-service).

```
class Automobile
{
    public string Model;
    public int MaxSpeed;
    public int Power
}

var result = Dll.GetAutomobile() // for example this method return Automobile
WebService.SaveAutomobile(result) // this method should take this argument
```

I can make it only in such way:

```
Dll.Automobile result = Dll.GetAutomobile() //instead var it's type(for understanding)

WebService.Automobile result2 = new WebService.Automobile();
result2.Model = result.Model;
result2.MaxSpeed = result.MaxSpeed;
result2.Power = result.Power;
```

Is there direct way to make `result2 = result`?

Comment: You could use something like `Automapper` if you cannot change the web service.

Comment: Or maybe you can try:

`WebService.Automobile result2 = new WebService.Automobile {
  Model = result.Model,
  MaxSpeed = result.MaxSpeed,
  Power = result.Power
};`

Comment: @Ruly. The main reason that I don't want to use such method is that this class is `List<Automobile>`. And reassignment of `List<Automobile>` will take time. @Belogix. I can change web service so is there some fast and direct way?

Comment: Why do you use Automobile from two different libraries? Can't you just use one?

Comment: @Ruly. There is client software what make some operation and gathered result of those operation. Software just use dll(what developed by me) in proper way and result of this work send to WebService. Class stucture is very easy so it is not very good use common big dll in both place when on webservice is necessary only Class Automobile from that .dll. If there is some way to pass into dll classtype from webservice and use inside dll it will be good too. The main point that all of those parts code are developed by me and I can change each part. But how? It is a big question.

Comment: Inside your WebService, do you use the same Dll (that contains the Automotive) or you create a new one?

Comment: @Ruly. Inside webservice I just use Automobile class without using that Dll. Dll make some collection data on client side. With a help of webservice I sent this data on server and store in database. So webservice hasn't this Dll. It has just copied class from Dll.

Comment: I think the easiest way is follow M-Peror answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the easiest way is to share a (third) DLL with the definition of class Automobile, between the calling DLL and the webservice.
So, create a library with the class Automobile, and have both the calling DLL and the webservice reference that library.

The disadvantage is that if you ever want to upgrade the library that contains Automobile, you have to update both (client and server) at the same time. It depends on your situation if that poses a problem or not. Also, this assumes you have control over both the server and client.

Comment: That is the easy way. I supose the way to go is using DTO (Data Transfer Objects): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: @Jordi, agreed. Updated my answer accordingly.